# Como fazer um submit com <button type="button">?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, button

eu criei alguns  e preciso que eles realizem as mesmas funções (com banco de dados) do  como cadastrar, alterar, etc. Alguém pode me ajudar ou me explicar como faço isso?

Obrigado !

Comment: criou alguns o que? Alguns formulários?

Comment: Tenho um formulário. Nesse mesmo preciso alterar, consultar, excluir e cadastrar. Porém, quando clico em algum outro fora de "cadastrar", esta me enviando para o form de cadastro novamente

Comment: como está seu `<a href="tela" >Tela </a>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com javascript você pode ao clicar no button invocar o evento submit do form:

HTML:

```
<form id="meu_form">
  <button id="enviar" type="button"> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('meu_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, esclareceu bastante. Porém, surgiu outra duvida. Eu preciso fazer um select numa tabela, porém, quando clico nesse botão, está me enviando para o formulario da minha tela. (e nao quero isso) Lembrando que minha tela esta dividida por abas, por isso nao quero alterar. Especificação do cliente

Comment: Tenho um formulário. Nesse mesmo preciso alterar, consultar, excluir e cadastrar. Porém, quando clico em algum outro fora de "cadastrar", esta me enviando para o form de cadastro novamente

Comment: Interessante suas dúvidas mas está fora do escopo dessa pergunta @RodrigoCaio, você pode fazer outra pergunta detalhando isso que acabou de comentar, pois se alterar essa irá invalidar a minha resposta.Se possível detalhe melhor o que se busca e poste os trechos relevantes de código.

Comment: Amigo, consegui resolver o problema. Na verdade, eu estava colocando o <form> antes tas minhas tags de abas, por isso ele estava ocupando o meu (.php) como um todo. Coloquei ele dentro da aba, e resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado ! Agora como faço para fechar esta questão?

Comment: Se a minha resposta atendeu, é só marcar como aceita (tem um sinal de positivo, logo abaixo da contagem de votos nela) =]